# How to do attribute to property conversion in Vue 3 / Custom Elements?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, custom-element

I am porting a component library from Angular JS and Lit to Vue 3 components. Big requirement is that components must be used from any framework, so they must be distributed as Custom Elements.

Several components have non-primitive component attributes/props. Let's take for example a simplified dropdown that would have options as an array. In Vue, you would write it as:

```js
<MyDropDown :options='["foo", "faa", "bar"]'>
```

As a custom element (in plain HTML), you should be able to write it as JSON

```html
<my-drop-down options='["foo", "faa", "bar"]'>
```

...or in our current implementation we have some logic to convert comma separated strings to array

```html
<my-drop-down options="foo,faa,bar">
```

The underlying property should always remain an array, so that no matter what the framework, the JavaScript should be

```js
getElementsByTagName("my-drop-down")[0].options = ["foo", "faa", "bar"];
```

I cannot find any way of doing this in Vue 3. In Lit we did this with Custom Converters: https://lit.dev/docs/v1/components/properties/#conversion-converter

Is there anything similar that I could do in Vue3?

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#using-custom-elements-in-vue